# What is the biding site code recognized by the parts of the spliceosome

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, dna, proteins, biophysics

Another question about [another Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kOGOY7vthk). At 0:50, the splicing process begins to remove the non-coding section of the DNA (intron), so the different parts of the spliceosome attach to the borders on the intron.

My question is, what is the code found in the borders of the intron which is recognized by the parts of the spliceosome, so they attach to it ?

For example, in the transcription of the DNA, the process begins after the transcription factor "TBP" recognizes the code "TATA" in the DNA string, then attaches to it. This triggers a whole process described by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MfSYnItYvg).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try googling "splice site recognition sequences"?

In general, the first two letters of the intron must be GT, the next three are often ARG.

The last three letters of the acceptor site of the intron are virtually always YAG

Comment: Thanks !! Do some section inside the intron play a role in this process ?

Comment: Well the GT-AG motif is inside the intron (the actual consensus sequences for humans are 5'-(C/A)G|GU(A/G)AGU ... NCAG|G-3', | denotes the intron/exon boundary). Additionally, there is a branchpoint site near the 3' end of the intron which has consensus sequence YNYURAY followed by poly-Y. The A is highly conserved and its 2'-OH is used to join the 5' end of the intron, creating the lariat. Also, note that because splicing requires high precision (an indel of 1 nucleotide means a frame-shift mutation), the spliceosome has additional mechanisms to ensure the splice site is selected accurately.